# Google analytics to track support for navigator.geolocation API?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, geolocation, gps

The navigator.geolocation api for user positioning is now also supported by Firefox and not just Safari/Iphone. I suspect it will become a well suported api as more devices support positioning.

Anyone know how to detect support of this api so that google analytics can chart it?

Comment: you may have to wait till Google adds it, however in the mean time... your iPhone/Firefox3.5+ users will support it. If it is enabled is obviously another question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unsure of the exact code, but you should be able to use [custom tracking events](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/eventTrackerGuide.html). Here's some some psuedo code:

```
if (navigation.geolocation) {
    _trackEvent(category, action, optional_label, optional_value)
}
```